# incompatibility issue between scikit-learn 0.24.1 and scikit-optimize 0.8.1

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, skopt

I have scikit-learn 0.24.1 and scikit-optimize 0.8.1, when I tried to use the BayesSearchCV function it gave me this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iid'
```

when I searched it turned out that the 'iid' is deprecated in the new scikit-learn, any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: `iid` is not deprecated. Could you add the code causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered the same issue, and I found that scikit-learn has deprecated the **iid** param. Temporarily,  I have downgraded the scikit-learn version to <= 0.23.2 , and it solved my problem.

You can downgrade it using : `pip install 'scikit-learn==0.23.2'` or lower.

Answer (score 0):

As it says here, 'iid' is deprecated:

https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues/978